# Error : "Pine cannot determine the referencing length oh a serie Try using max_bars_back"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to improve this script (to identify the gaps), everything works but I still have an error message that occurs after a few minutes:

"Pine cannot determine the referencing length oh a serie Try using max_bars_back in the study or strategy function"
I tried but it didn't work. From what I understand, when the buffer is full it can no longer calculate.

I think need to create a loop that refreshes. (When I change the time unit or I refresh the indicator it works) I tried the indications of this site but I am not competent enough to master everything
https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000587849-i-see-pine-cannot-determine-the-referencing-length-of-a-series-try-using-max-bars-back-error/

Can you help me ? It would be super!

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Asch-

//@version=5
indicator(title='GAP DETECTOR fini DAX DJI', overlay=true, max_bars_back=500, max_lines_count = 500)


var i = input.int(450, "Length ", minval = 1)


///////////// Make a loop to refresh the indicator ? Word when i refresh the indicator or change the UT

length = bar_index > 500 ? i : na

//// not understand useless ?
passed_length = bar_index == 0 ? 500 : length
///// 

width = input.int(2, options=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

gap_start = high[length]
gap_end = low[length - 1]


gap_bull = false
gap_bear = false

inf_gap = 0.0
sup_gap = 0.0

if barstate.islast

    for j = 1 to length by 1
        gap_bull := false
        gap_bear = false
        
        inf_gap := 0.0
        sup_gap := 0.0

        if high[j] < low[j - 1]  //bull gap
            gap_start := high[j]
            gap_end := low[j - 1]
            gap_bull := true
            inf_gap := gap_start
            sup_gap := gap_end
            for i = j - 1 to 0 by 1
                sup_gap := math.min(sup_gap, low[i])
                sup_gap
            if (sup_gap - inf_gap) / (syminfo.mintick * 10) < 5  // only gap > 5 pips are considered
                gap_bull := false
                gap_bull

        if low[j] > high[j - 1]  //bear gap
            gap_start := low[j]
            gap_end := high[j - 1]
            gap_bear := true
            inf_gap := gap_end
            sup_gap := gap_start
            for i = j - 1 to 0 by 1
                inf_gap := math.max(inf_gap, high[i])
                inf_gap
            if (sup_gap - inf_gap) / (syminfo.mintick * 10) < 5  // only gap > 5 pips are considered
                gap_bear := false
                gap_bear
/////////////////////////WORK 
        if gap_bull


            label_bull = label.new(bar_index[j], na, 'Bull gap: ' + str.tostring((sup_gap - inf_gap) / (syminfo.mintick * 100)) + ' pips\n' + '[' + str.tostring(inf_gap) + ' ; ' + str.tostring(sup_gap) + ']', color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.belowbar)  
//label.delete(label_bull[1])

            
            boxbull = box.new(left=bar_index[j], top=sup_gap, right=bar_index + 100, bottom=inf_gap, border_width=2)
            box.set_border_color(boxbull, color=color.new(color.green, 50))
            box.set_border_width(boxbull, 1)
            box.set_bgcolor(boxbull, color.new(color.green, 70))
            box.delete(boxbull[1])


        if gap_bear
        
            boxbear = box.new(left=bar_index[j], top=sup_gap, right=bar_index + 100, bottom=inf_gap, border_width=2)
            box.set_border_color(boxbear, color=color.new(color.red, 50))
            box.set_border_width(boxbear, 1)
            box.set_bgcolor(boxbear, color.new(color.red, 70))
            box.delete(boxbear[1])
            
            
            label_bear = label.new(bar_index[j], na, 'Bear gap: ' + str.tostring((sup_gap - inf_gap) / (syminfo.mintick * 100)) + ' pips\n' + '[' + str.tostring(inf_gap) + ' ; ' + str.tostring(sup_gap) + ']', color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
            //label.delete(label_bear[1])
           
//line.delete(line_bear_sup[1])
```

[Photo of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fzN9.jpg)

Comment: What ticketid and timeframe are you on?
I pasted the code in my editor and no error message, just some warnings, but by no means your described error. It seems to be working fine on eg.: SP500 or TSLA from 1h to 1M

Comment: Yes, it is in UT 2min or UT 5min, after some time, maybe 15min, the error message appears. I'm on TVC:DJI for example

Comment: Well, the problem sounds very much like what the docs say: "If the indicator or strategy 'max_bars_back' parameter is used, all variables in the indicator are affected. This may result in excessive memory usage and cause runtime problems. When possible (i.e. when the cause is a variable rather than a function), please use the max_bars_back function instead." Unfortunately I don't know what the best solution would be, but I'd try to avoid using max_bars_back on the indicator level. I also cannot reproduce the problem what makes debugging also very difficult. I hope you'll find a solution